Database Inspector: Can't open offline database /data/data/my_package_name/databases/my_database ; device 'my_device' not found
Ok so I've already been fighting with some errors for about 2 days and I managed to collect different answers and information from the Internet about them but still to no success. As a consequence, I think it is time to shed more light on them if possible. The main error which I am fighting with now is:

Database Inspector: Can't open offline database /data/data/my_package_name/databases/my_database ; device 'my_device' not found

Of course, the first question is why does this error appears and how to get rid of it? How can the device be not found as long as it is connected to the ide and this thing is clearly shown in the device manager? It appeared as soon as I started experimenting with Room database. I tried to solve it in different ways and here is what I've found, but hopefully you can add more insights:
One answer on StackOverflow, whose link I've lost, suggested that the problem might be because that folder does not actually exist. As bizarre as it may sound, because in other projects the basic app folder is created in the Android folder of the phone, I can't indeed find that folder on my phone. So, I further digged into the problem and found this:
After install internal storage Android>data folder not created
To conclude, I somehow managed to make the app inspector work in a previsible manner. Thus, only after I insert, relaunch the app, open the app inspector, disconnect and reconnect, the tables appear, but in the beginning the db is shown as closed. I am pretty sure they should appear from the beginning, but I'm not sure what I am missing. Maybe, I don't open the db correctly. I've even changed my usb cable in order to be sure the phone just not randomly disconnects from the ide.
Thanks in advance for any hints!

Your error is "device 'my_device' not found". To me, that implies a shaky USB connection between your development machine and your test device. I have had that happen from crappy cables and from wobbly USB ports.

Yes, my phone is Android 10 so maybe a bit old, but the cable is new. It might be from the phone's end. But there is still the rest of the post to be answered.

First make sure your USB / adb connection is working without any problem. Try to run e.g. adb shell on command-line. For the other questions please do not post multiple question in one post.

I edited the question so as to contain only the first question. I will probably come back with the second one. In the meantime I managed to make the database work, I mean to show the changes in the UI. I'm still not completely sure what caused the App Inspector problem but I will try the adb way.
